Vscode always delete my code when I am saving my css code
when I am using Vscode coding my Vue project, everytime I saved code, then Vscode deleted my css code. I don't know where it can be set so that it do not delete my code.
I woted css code like this: display: -webkit-box after I saved code, the code is changed to display: box.

Hm, to me this sounds like a build tool or something like that because it's removing the prefix. Does this happen when you are not running your code? Does this happen if you disable all extensions and then try it?

As a temporary solution, you can run 'File: Save without Formatting' by hitting Ctrl+K  Ctrl+Shift+S

thank you . I found the solution. the reason is I used stylelint. after I disabled the styelint using // stylelint-disable-next-line. It works very well.

so you have the vscode stylelint extension installed?

it is @starball

This behaviour was due to usage of Stylelint. The asker worked around it by using // stylelint-disable-next-line to disable linting for that particular line. See also https://github.com/stylelint/vscode-stylelint?tab=readme-ov-file#editorcodeactionsonsave and https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure.
